# How to look at most up-to-date forks of a project with a huge number of forks

Tags: git, github, openhab

I plan to work with [OpenHAB](http://www.openhab.org/), so I go to its [GitHub page](https://github.com/openhab/openhab) and think about [which fork to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372063/how-to-choose-the-right-branch-fork-to-use-by-looking-on-the-githubs-network-gr), when I suddenly realize that I can't look at the [network graph](https://github.com/openhab/openhab/network) and so not decide which fork to use.

How can I make only somewhat recent forks (e.g. activity in the last two months) in *any* GitHub project visible?

**EDIT:** I don't want a random fork. For that I would go to the [member site](https://github.com/openhab/openhab/network/members), hit Ctrl+F and smash the keyboard for the next best entry. Recent activity in the forks is a criteria.

I don't care if I can archieve this with GitHub, git or a third party tool.

Comment: Why would you want to pick some random fork of a project?  The main project itself appears to have very recent activity.  In general I would never pick a fork over the primary project unless there was a specific feature set I wanted, in which case the answer to "which fork should I use?" is "the one that implements the specific feature".

Comment: @larsks The point is that I can't **see** "the one that implements the specific feature" if I tried to. And although it may not be the case in this specific example with OpenHAB, the question remains how to choose a decent fork when the main project is somewhat abandomed.